# Shift tab not retaining the element focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Javascript version code -- [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/6QJxImYUyuaCBl1m140O?p=preview)

```
 if (el.value.length > 1) {
    el.value = el.value[el.value.length - 1];
  }
  try {
    if (el.value == null || el.value == "") {
      this.foucusOnInput(el.previousElementSibling);
    } else {
      this.foucusOnInput(el.nextElementSibling);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

AngularJS version code - [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/KBkWdz1dQoxwWncprFSx?p=info)

```
if (ele.currentTarget.value.length >= 1) {
            ele.currentTarget.value = ele.currentTarget.value[ele.currentTarget.value.length - 1];
  }
        try {
            if (ele.currentTarget.value === null || ele.currentTarget.value === "") {
                foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.previousElementSibling);
            } else {
                foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Not able to implement the javascript version of

> Tab & Shift+Tab

functionality in AngularJS. Let me know what am missing here!

Requirement - Once you enter the value to the input text the next input text element should be focused; On Shift-Tab previous input text element should be focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution -- [Link](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/IkguaMjEGodmeRJS?preview)

```
if(ele.key != "Tab" && ele.key != "Shift" ){
            if (ele.currentTarget.value.length >= 1) {
                ele.currentTarget.value = ele.currentTarget.value[ele.currentTarget.value.length - 1];
            }
            try {
                if (ele.currentTarget.value === null || ele.currentTarget.value === "") {
                    foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.previousElementSibling);
                } else {
                    foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyup event gets triggered for every key up including tab and shift. This is the difference between your javascript solution angularjs solution.

I'm not sure if there is an equivalent to oninput in angularjs. 'keyup', 'keydown', 'input' all work differently. There is ng-change in angularjs but it requires ng-model on the input element and I don't think $event works with ng-change.

Anyway, there is a working solution. Try this:

```
$scope.readKey = function(ele) {
        console.log(ele);
        if(ele.shiftKey) return;
        if (ele.currentTarget.value.length >= 1) {
            ele.currentTarget.value = ele.currentTarget.value[ele.currentTarget.value.length - 1];
        }
        try {
            if (ele.currentTarget.value === null || ele.currentTarget.value === "" ) {
                foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.previousElementSibling);
            } else {
                foucusOnInput(ele.currentTarget.nextElementSibling);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

This code, as listened on keyup instead of input, will not allow to go to next input field if current input field is empty. In your javascript example, the code in input handler never gets executed and so you can move to next input field if current one is empty.

If you want to achieve the same thing in angularjs solution as well, then try changing the condition to this:

```
if(ele.shiftKey || ele.keyCode === 9) return;
```

This prevents the code from getting executed if its shift key or tab key. 9 is the keycode for TAB.

Comment: @JohnSmith, If it helped, can you accept my answer?